# Symmetric polynomials and the Newton identities

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I want to write
$P(x,y,z)=yx^{3}+zx^{3}+xy^{3}+zy^{3}+xz^{3}+yz^{3}$
in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials, but I'm getting stuck at the first step. I know I should follow the proof of the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials using the Newton identities.

First I pick out the 'biggest' monomial according to the lexicographical ordering: $yz^{3}$. Now I want to rewrite this as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials. I don't quite understand how to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By Gauss's algorithm below, if  $\rm\ z^a\,y^b\, x^c\ $ is the highest w.r.t. lex order $\rm\ z > y > x\ $ then we subtract $\rm\ s_1^{a-b}\ s_2^{b-c}\ s_3^c\,$ to decrease its order. In our example $\rm\, z^3\, y\, $ is highest, therefore we  subtract $\rm\ s_1^{3-1}\ s_2^{1-0}\ s_3^0 = (x+y+z)^2\ (xy+yz+zx)\,$ from $\rm\,P.\,$ The result is smaller in lex-order, hence iterating this reduction rewrites $\rm\:P\:$ as a polynomial in elementary symmetric polynomials $\rm\,s_i.\,$ Here the algorithm terminates in two more steps - see below. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2386889/242) for another worked example.

As I mentioned in a [prior post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/using-grobner-bases-for-solving-polynomial-equations/3562#3562), Gauss's algorithm is the earliest known example of using lex-order reduction as in the Grobner basis algorithm. For a nice exposition see Chapter 7 of Cox, Little, O'Shea: *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms*. They also give generalizations to  the ring of invariants of a finite matrix group $\rm G \subset  GL(n,k)$. Below is an excerpt which, coincidentally, presents this example. You might find it helpful to first read the example at the end before reading the proof.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Bill, I have to ask, given that it's Gauss: which algorithm?

Comment: @J.M. Recall my prior post on [Gauss's algorithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/using-grobner-bases-for-solving-polynomial-equations/3562#3562), which has a reference. Alas, it appears nobody read it since it got no votes.

Comment: Thanks for the refresh; I would think I ran out of upvotes that day I commented on it though...

Comment: @J.M. Ah, I only just now noticed that you too commented on the prior post. What a coincidence.

Comment: The first paragraph is interesting; motivating towards some work of Gauss still in modern algebra.

Answer (score 9):

Edit: As per Bill's comment I would like to clarify that this is not related to Gauss' proof.

$$P(x,y,z)=yx^{3}+zx^{3}+xy^{3}+zy^{3}+xz^{3}+yz^{3}$$
$$=x^3(y+z+x-x)+y^3(x+z+y-y)+z^3(x+y+z-z)$$
$$=x^3(x+y+z)+y^3(x+y+z)+z^3(x+y+z)-x^4-y^4-z^4$$
$$=(x+y+z)(x^3+y^3+z^3)-(x^4+y^4+z^4)$$

Now you can use identities for [power sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials).

Comment: @Timothy: do you mind breaking the formula into two displayed lines? It is running out of the displayport on my small netbook.

Comment: @Willie: Yeah I just did that after I saw how horrible it looked :)

Comment: @Timothy: The OP's remarks make it clear that he is attempting to understand the classic Gauss proof using lex-order. But the above approach is of no help in this regard.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I am not aware of Gauss' proof about this. I interpreted OP's statements to mean that the said proof was a possible approach and not necessarily the approach the OP had to use.

Comment: @Timothy: See the second paragraph of the OP's post where he mentions picking out the highest term in lex-order. This is the reduction step in Gauss's algoritm - see my answer.

Comment: @Bill: Yes I had read it. I don't see how that contradicts my earlier statement.

Comment: @Timothy: Does the method above yield an algorithm to rewrite every symmetric polynomial in elementary symmetric functions or is it an ad-hoc method that works only for the above specific case?

Comment: @Bill: I never claimed it does. The OP's first statement says that he wants to write the given polynomial in terms of elementary symmetric functions. That is the question I answered. He explained his approach. I never claimed mine was the same approach. The OP did not claim that he wants to solve this problem using Gauss' proof. The OP said he tried solving this problem using Gauss' proof.

Comment: @Timothy: Not true. The OP explicitly wrote "I know I should follow [Gauss's] proof of the fundamental theorem". At the least you should preface your answer saying that it does not follow this proof so that readers don't needlessly waste their time having to infer that.

Comment: @Bill: I have prefaced it as per your demand. You can feel free to edit the edit. I stand by all my earlier statements.

Comment: @Timothy: Thanks for clarifying your post. Of course there's nothing wrong with giving alternative approaches. But it's always helpful to *explicitly* specify that's what you're doing, so that the reader isn't left puzzled trying to determine how the alternative approach is related to the approach sought - when in fact it is not. That's why I suggested that it would be helpful to add some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You stated:

> I want to write
> $P(x,y,z)=yx^{3}+zx^{3}+xy^{3}+zy^{3}+xz^{3}+yz^{3}$
> in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials,

The polynomial $P$ is homogeneous of degree $4$ and highest
degree $3$. Therefore, using partitions of $4$ it can be
written as a linear combination of the elementary symmetric functions $$e_1:=x+y+z,\; e_2:=xy+xz+yz,\; e_3:=xyz$$
of $x,y,z$ as
$$ P(x,y,z) = S := a\,e_3e_1 +b\,e_2^2 +c\,e_2e_1^2 +d\,e_1^4. $$
Now $d=0$ since the highest degree of $P$ is $3$. Now, the expansion of
$S$ has highest degree term of $x$ as $c\,x^3(y+z).$ Comparing this to
$P$ implies $c=1.$ But now, the expansion of $S$ contains $(b+2)x^2z^2$
which implies $b=-2.$ Now the expansion of $S$ contains
$(a+1)x^2yz$ which implies $a=-1.$ The final result is the equation
$$ P(x,y,z) = -e_3e_1 -2\,e_2^2 +e_2e_1^2. $$