# Solve equation $5x^2+3x - 4 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to derive full square but haven't managed to get anything useful from it. The question is: what is (more or less) general method for solving such equations?

Comment: The quadratic equation still works.

Comment: @TokenToucan You mean solving it through discriminant?

Comment: The quadratic formula [works over any field where $\,2\neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29893/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque But what if I get discriminant that is not integer? It seems to be a problem

Comment: The discriminant is $b^2-4ac$: must be an integer. If it’s a nonzero square in $\Bbb Z/17\Bbb Z$, you have two roots. Just do it.

Comment: @BillDubuque Well, in this case it isn't and I wonder what to do

Comment: Here the discriminant $\equiv 89\equiv 2^2\,$. The usual proof by completing the square shows it has a root in the field  $\iff$ the discriminant is a square. This is proved here in many places (including (implcitly) my prior link).

Comment: This provides no insight, but you could also do 17 elementary calculations to solve the equation.

Answer (score 0):

In this field, the discriminant is a square:
$$\Delta=9-4\cdot 5\cdot -4=89\equiv 4\mod 17,$$
hence the roots are
$$x_0,x_1=(-3\pm 2)\cdot 10^{-1}=\begin{cases}-5\cdot -5\equiv 8\\
-1\cdot-5=5\end{cases}$$

*Completing the square*:

First multiply the equation by $5^{-1}=7$.  You obtain:
$$x^2+4x+6=(x+2)^2+2=(x+2)^2-7^2,$$
whence $x=-2\pm 7$.