# If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the zeros of $x^3 + 4x + 1=0$, compute a expression containing them

Tags: polynomials

If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the zeros of $x^3 + 4x + 1$, then calculate the value of: $$(\alpha + \beta)–1 + (\beta + \gamma)–1 + (\gamma + \alpha)–1$$

Comment: Is it a contest problem?

Comment: Do you mean $4^x$, as in the title, or $4x$, as in the question? Since you say polynomial, I assume the latter.

Comment: I get the feeling that the expression should be reciprocals, otherwise the problem is fairly trivial (it doesn't seem to be too much harder however)

Comment: The poster must have made a TeX error; it must be reciprocals.  So, put the expression as a single fraction, and use the fact that symmetric rational functions of the roots are rational functions of the coefficients.  Multiply out $(x - \alpha) (x - \beta) (x - \gamma)$ to se how.

Answer (score 6):

HINT: You want to calculates $2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)-3$. There is a formula to find $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ when you know the coeficients of the polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $(\alpha + \beta)-1+(\beta+\gamma)-1+(\gamma +\alpha)-1=\left(2\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma\right)-3=2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)-3$. We know from [Vieta's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) that:

$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-\frac{0}{1}=0$$

Therefore, $(α + β)–1 + (β + γ)–1 + (γ + α)–1=2(0)-3=-3$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Sum of the roots of equation : $x^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ is $-b$.

So convert it into this form. You see that co-efficient of $x^2$ is zero, so the expression's value is $-3$.

**Hail Vieta!!**

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Exploit symmetry. The sum $\rm = 2(a+b+c) - 3,\:$ and $\rm\:a+b+c = $ -coef of $\rm\,x^2\,$ by [Vieta.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas)

**Remark** $\ $ Generally one can calculate any symmetric polynomial of the roots in the same way, since, by a simple [algorithm of Gauss](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/233102/23500), any symmetric polynomial may be written as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials  [(Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: So you want $2(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) - 3$ ?