# Algebra Difference in Roots Question.

Tags: contest-math

> Let D be the absolute value of the difference of the 2 roots of the equation 3x^2-10x-201=0. Find [D]. [x] denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to x.

I came across this question in a Math Competition and I am not sure how to solve it without using a calculator, since calculators are not allowed in the competition. Thanks.

Comment: Can we assume familiarity with the quadratic formula?

Comment: You mean, the general formula which allows you to find the 2 roots?

Comment: Yes.  I answered the question assuming that this formula is available to those entering this challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $a, b$ are the roots, 
$$|a-b|^2 = (a-b)^2 = (a+b)^2 - 4 ab = \frac{100}9+4\times \frac{201}3 = \frac{2512}9$$

Comment: I've never seen this relationship between the roots of a quadratic...  Is this a serious gap in my education, or a more minor note that I missed along the way?  Also, I can't seem to see the relationship between this and the original quadratic...

Comment: @abiessu  $|a-b|^2=(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab$ holds true for all real $a, b$, not just roots. We use the fact that they are roots to quickly find the values of $a+b, ab$ using coefficients of the quadratic (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Vieta.27s_formulas).  Useful to know, IMHO.

Comment: Got it, it just took me an extra moment to realize where the formulas came from.

Comment: @abiessu The possible gap is the Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials - see my answer. The essence of the matter will become clearer if you study Galois Theory.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ By $ $ Vieta, $\,\ x^2 -\frac{10}3 x - 67\, =\, (x-a)(x-b)\iff \ \color{#0a0}{a+b} = 10/3,\ \color{#c00}{ab} = -67$

$(a-b)^2$ is *symmetric* in $\,a,b\,$ so by [FTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) it can be written as a polynomial in $\,\color{#0a0}{a+b},\ \color{#c00}{ab}$

Indeed, applying [Gauss's Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652298/242) we find that $\, (a-b)^2 = (\color{#0a0}{a+b})^2 -4\color{#c00}{ab}\, =\, \dfrac{16\cdot 157}9$

**Remark** $\ $ The same *algorithm* works for polynomials in any number of variables.  It reduces problem like this to rote *mechanical* computation, i.e. no guesswork is required to solve such problems, only simple polynomial arithmetic. The algorithm yields a constructive interpretation of the [FTSP = Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) that every symmetric polynomial has a unique representation as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Gauss's algorithm may be viewed as a special case of Gröbner basis methods (which may be viewed both as a multivariate generalization of the (Euclidean) polynomial division algorithm, as well as a nonlinear genralization of Gaussian elimination for linear systems of equation). Gauss's algorithm is the earliest known use of such  a lexicographic order for term-rewriting (now mechanized by the Grobner basis algorithm and related methods).

Comment: Very nice; I had missed symmetric polynomials in my undergraduate education, and while I have noticed them on occasion here on Math.SE and elsewhere, I haven't had much chance to incorporate them into what I understand of mathematics.

Comment: @abiessu Symmetry plays a large role in solving many problems, so it is well-worth studying it (one will learn the basics in most courses on abstract agebra). Above it is a bit overkill to use Gauss's algorithm, but I wanted to make it clear that the process is completely mechanical/algorithmic - nothing needs to be pulled out of a hat like magic. [Here are some other answers](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+(dubuque+OR+%22key+ideas%22+OR+%22math+gems%22)+exploit+innate+symmetry) that exploit innate symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

$$3x^2-10x-201=0\\ \iff x^2-\frac{10}3x-67=0$$
Assuming the quadratic formula is available to use,
$$x=\frac{10}6\pm\frac{\sqrt{\frac{100}9+4\cdot 67}}2\\=\frac 53\pm\sqrt{\frac{25}9+67}$$

So the square root term is greater than $\sqrt{64}$ but less than $\sqrt{81}$ and is therefore between $8$ and $9$ in value, and therefore the difference between the roots can be either be $16$ or $17$, but not $18$ since that term is less than $9$.

The difference can be determined this way because both roots have the offset fraction $\dfrac53$ which is removed upon subtraction.

To determine whether the difference is greater than $17$, consider whether the square root term is greater than $8.5:$

$$(8+0.5)^2=64+2\cdot8\cdot0.5+0.25=67+5+0.25$$

And our original square root term contains

$$67+\frac{25}9=67+2+\frac79$$

Therefore, half of the difference between the roots is less than $8.5$ but greater than $8$ and therefore the total difference is between $16$ and $17$, leaving $16$ as the value of $[D]$.

Comment: This is a "brute force" way of attacking this problem, Macavity has listed a good shortcut in another answer.