# If $a,b$ are the roots of the equation $2 x^2 -3 x +1 = 0$, find an equation whose roots are $a/(2b +3)$, $b/(2a +3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If $a,b$ are the roots of the equation $2 x^2 -3 x +1 = 0$, find an equation whose roots are $a/(2b +3)$, $b/(2a +3)$

I was practicing quadratic equation questions online but I am stuck on this question.

I found the values of roots $a= 1$, $b= 1/2$

Comment: Did you find the roots $a$ and $b$?

Comment: value of roots a= 1, b= 1/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots have product $\,=\color{#c00}{ab}/(4\color{#c00}{ab}+6(\color{#0a0}{a\!+\!b}) + 9)\,$ and we know $\,\color{#c00}{ab}=1/2,\ \color{#0a0}{a+b}=3/2.\,$ Similary their sum is symmetric in $\,a,b\,$ so it can be written as a polynomial in $\,ab\,$ and $\,a\!+\!b.$

This gives their sum $\,s\,$ and product $\,p.\,$ By Vieta they are the roots of $\,x^2-s\,x+p\, =\, 0.$

**Remark** $\ $ Note that this way we don't need to compute the roots. Rather, we derive a formula that maps the coefficients of the quadratic for the original roots into the coefficients of the quadratic for the transformed roots. This works universally for any given quadratic - whose roots might be hairy *irrational* numbers. But this way avoids calculating with irrationals, instead working only with the simpler *rational* coefficients.

This is a simple example of exploiting the innate *symmetry* of a problem - here that the coefficients are (elementary) *symmetric* polynomials of the roots, and every symmetric polynomial can be written as a polynomial in these elementary symmetric polynomials. In fact there is a [simple algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652298/242) to do by Gauss (though that would be overkill here).

Comment: you've edited your post n number of times :P :D
and it's worth it :D
Good job
Thank you for your precious comment 
God bless you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your new equation is $(x-\frac a{2b+3})(x-\frac b{2a+3})=0$  Do you see why?  Can you find $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Got it!
Thank you
God bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

use the Quadratic root formula to find the values of a and b. 
calculate the two new roots: $a'=\frac{a}{2b+3}$ and $b'=\frac{b}{2a+3}$. Simply plug these new values within $$(x - a')(x - b')$$  Now multiply the two parentheses and you're done.

Comment: Got it.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @amighty No, you're not done because the product still involves $\,a\,$ and $\,b,\,$ You don't need to compute the roots if your exploit the innate *symmetry* - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque I've seen your post and it's good.
Thank you for being so helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to not to calculate the roots. The new equation is $x^2-Sx+P=0$ where
$$P={a\over 2b+3}.{b\over 2a+3}={ab\over 4ab+6(a+b)+9}={{1\over 2}\over 4\times{1\over 2}+6({3\over 2})+9}$$
and $$S={a\over 2b+3}+{b\over 2a+3}={2a^2+3a+2b^2+3b\over 4ab+6(a+b)+9}={2\big((a+b)^2-2ab)\big)+3(a+b)\over 4ab+6(a+b)+9}$$

Comment: Thank you.
Good way to solve such question.
God bless you :)