# How to express a symmetric polynomial in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Can someone explain how to express a polynomial in terms of elementary symmetric polynomial.
(where there is possible) ?
For example if i have the polynomials:

$t_1^3+t_2^3$

$t_1t_2^2+t_2t_3^2+t_3t_1^2$

$t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^3$

Comment: Only symmetric polynomials can be expressed in terms of combinations of symmetric polynomials. Also, the first polynomial isn't symmetric.

Comment: Don Thousand yes you mean : $t_1t_2^2+t_2t_3^2+t_3t_1^3$ right ,the 2nd one?

Comment: @Don Thousand can u explain how to express a symmetric polynomial in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials??

Comment: @rogerl no cuz the answers there connected yo computer science not math!

Comment: @Almaa Okay, how about [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14051/symmetric-polynomials-and-the-newton-identities/14061#14061)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your first polynomial for instance, which is symmetric in two variables: $x^3 + y^3$. We know that the ring of symmetric polynomials in two variables is generated by $e_1 = x + y$ and $e_2 = xy$, and we have
$$ e_1^3 = x^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2 + y^3 = (x^3 + y^3) + 3 xy (x + y) = (x^3 + y^3) + 3 e_2 e_1,$$
and hence $x^3 + y^3 = e_1^3 - 3 e_1 e_2$.

You can do the same ad-hoc method in three variables and you'll quickly find an answer. If you want to see more sophisticated ways of doing this, consult a book on symmetric function theory.