# Finding $|ab+bc+ca|$ with $a+b+c=2$ and $\sum_{cyc}(a^2+ab+b^2)(b^2+bc+c^2)=625+\frac34(ab+bc+ca)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers

> Given $a,b,c$ are three reals, $a+b+c=2$ and
> $$\begin{align}
> (a^2+ab+b^2)(b^2+bc+c^2)&+(b^2+bc+c^2)(c^2+ca+a^2)\\
> &+(c^2+ca+a^2)(a^2+ab+b^2)\\
> &=625+\frac34(ab+bc+ca)^2
> \end{align}$$ Find the value of $|ab+bc+ca|$.

Attempt:

First I tried theory of equations, but it didn’t help. Then I went as follows:

$$a^2+ab+b^2\ge3ab$$ so $$625+\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)^2}{4}\ge9(a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2) \tag1$$
Taking out $abc$ common, we get
$$625+\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)^2}{4}\ge18abc \tag2$$
Writing $(a+b+c)^2=4$ and some manipulations give
$$625+\frac{4}{3}\ge18abc \tag3$$

Now I’m stuck here, I’m not sure whether this question can be solved by inequality or not but still this is the best which I could do.

Comment: Now the condition changes: $a, b, c$ are reals with $a + b + c = 2$.

Comment: Yes since it seemed to be wrong otherwise.

Comment: If computer is allowed, it is easy. I think you want to do it by hand.

Comment: Yes I don’t want to use computer.

Comment: with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}\implies|ab+bc+ca|=14$

Comment: Please tell the approach.

Comment: You can simplify the quadratic equation to:
$$\left(2 a^2+a (b+c)+2 b^2+b c+2 c^2-50\right) \left(2 a^2+a (b+c)+2 b^2+b c+2 c^2+50\right)=0$$

Comment: I’m not able to understand how did you factorise the whole expression, please elaborate in detail.

Comment: [See Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+-625+%2B+a%5E4+%2B+b%5E4+%2B+b%5E3+c+%2B+3+b%5E2+c%5E2+%2B+b+c%5E3+%2B+c%5E4+%2B+a%5E3+%28b+%2B+c%29+%2B+++a+%28b+%2B+c%29%5E3+-+3%2F4+%28a+b+%2B+a+c+%2B+b+c%29%5E2+%2B+3+a%5E2+%28b%5E2+%2B+b+c+%2B+c%5E2%29)

Comment: So can’t it be factorised manually then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note we can express the cyclic sum in LHS in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials, like so:
$$\sum_{cyc} (a^2+ab+b^2)(b^2+bc+c^2)=(a+b+c)^4-3(a+b+c)^2(ab+bc+ca)+3(ab+bc+ca)^2$$
Hence using $a+b+c=2$, and letting $t=ab+bc+ca$, we have
$$16-12t+3t^2=625+\frac34t^2$$
$$\iff (t+14)(3t-58)=0$$

Now $t=\frac12(a+b+c)^2-\frac12(a^2+b^2+c^2)\leqslant2-\frac12t\implies t\leqslant \frac43$, thus $t=-14$.

P.S. *It is not hard to demonstrate there are solutions for $a+b+c=2$, $ab+bc+ca=-14$, for e.g. $\{a, b, c\}=\{1\pm\sqrt{15},0\}$ does the job.*

Comment: Can you please elaborate your approach used to convert the cyclic sum into such a nice expression?

Comment: Sometimes the approach is easy to notice, like having $a^4$ term on LHS needs $(a+b+c)^4$, and having $a^2b^2,..$ needs $(ab+bc+ca)^2$ etc. However if you want a generic procedure, check Gauss' algorithm referenced in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14051/symmetric-polynomials-and-the-newton-identities/14061#14061

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and reference.