# On the structure of a particular equation (maybe Sylvester's)

Tags: linear-algebra, sylvester-equation

I sincerely hope this question is interesting for you to answer.

Assume that $V\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times k}$, $B_i\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times 1}$, $T_i\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ with $i=1\dots k$, and, finally $L\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times k}$. I've the following equation to solve for V (all other matrices are assumed to be known):

$$\begin{equation} V - VB_1VT_1 - VB_2VT_2 - \dots - VB_kVT_k = L\end{equation}$$

I would like to know if such an equation can be classified as a particular equation with known solution, for example, a Sylvester equation (I know that the proposed equation is nonlinear though), or any other type, such that the solution can be found in a closed-form expression.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: This is a system of polynomial equations. [Gröbner basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550) may be useful.