# How to find the eigenvectors of a matrix function that is linear in its eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Let be $A(x) = x_1 A_1 + x_2 A_2 + x_3 A_3$, where $x = [ \, x_1 \; x_2 \; x_3 \,]^T\,$ is a real vector, $A_i$, $i=1,2,3$, are known $3\! \times \!3$ real matrices. How can I solve the following problem.

Find scalar $\lambda$ and vector $u$ such that

> $[ \, \lambda I_3 - A(u) \, ]\,u = 0, \quad \quad (\,1\,)$

where $I_3$ is the $3\! \times \!3$ identity matrix, $\lambda$ and $u$ are eigenvalue and eigenvector of $A(u)$, respectively.

Is there, in the literature, a tractable and feasible solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: If $u$ is an eigenvector of $A(u)$ maybe you should try to look what it implies.

Comment: I tried, but I an not a mathematician. So, I came to nowhere. However, I keep trying.

Comment: This is a set of polynomial equations. You need to calculate the Gröbner basis to solve it. See *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* written by Cox, Little and O'Shea. There are computer algebra systems for solving this kind of problems. [This old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550) may also be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Reading the "old question" that you recommended I saw the similarity between both questions.